# Functions mapped to themselves

Tags: number-theory

How many $1$-to-$1$ and onto functions are there for a function $f: A \longrightarrow A$ (i.e. a function mapped to itself)?

Comment: Is $A$ a finite set?

Comment: I am not sure, but I am guessing that it is (it reads an n-set to itself).

Comment: You mean a function from a set to itself.

Comment: @user161065 Is it clear to you that - when it comes to functions $A\rightarrow A$ where $A$ is a finite set - injective functions and surjective functions coincide?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** suppose $A = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.  Then each $1$-to-$1$ function $f:A \to A$ corresponds to an arrangement $(f(1),f(2),\dots,f(n))$ of the numbers from $1$ to $n$.